# Is the series $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0} x^{n}\cos(n\theta)$ absolutely convergent for $|x|<1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Determine if the series is absolutely convergent.
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}  x^{n}\cos(n\theta)$$ where $|x|<1, \theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone please help with proving this?

Comment: Compare with $\sum_{n \ge 0} x^n$

Comment: *Please give your questions more precise titles*; ideally, people should be able to understand exactly what it is you're asking just by looking at the title.

Comment: Can you prove that this series equals $(1-x^2)/2(x^2-2x\cos{\theta}+1) $?

Answer (score 4):

$|x^{n}\cos(n\theta)|=|x|^{n}|\cos(n\theta)|\le |x|^{n}$

So $\sum_0^n |x^{n}\cos(n\theta)| \le \sum_0^n |x|^{n} = \cfrac{1-|x|^{n+1}}{1-|x|}\le \cfrac{1}{1-|x|}$

$\sum_0^n |x^{n}\cos(n\theta)|$ is increasing and bounded aboveso it converges.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Note that
$$
0\leq \lvert x^n\cos(n)\rvert =\lvert x^n\rvert \;\lvert \cos(n)\rvert\leq \lvert x\rvert^n.
$$
Use the comparison test.